# How to do what this person did in this video tutorial?

Tags: modeling, light

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZshtugUVY3A

At around the 21 minute mark he seems to play with the lighting and material colour, but I can't find that in my blender settings! He seems like he has a different control panel, here's mine:

[image]

How can I do what he did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He selected the Lamp Object, and then went to the data panel.

As for your materials, one of your swatches is completely alpha (The current one in your screenshot).
Select it, click the Color swatch, and take the "A:" value all the way to 1.

Then match the positions on the ramp that the video has.

[image]

Comment: Where is this "A:" value?